# How to update product combination price in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

I want to create a custom module. Firstly I read a XML and get the price by this code:

```
$price = $product->attributes()->price->__toString();
```

Then update the product price by using Product object:

```
$product1 = new Product($id_product);
$product1->price = round($price - (18.69 / 100) * $price, 2);
$product1->save();
```

This works fine. But how to update combination in product. I have 'id_product_attribute' which I use to update quantity:

```
StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_product, $attribute['id_product_attribute'], $singleStock, $id_shop = null);
```

But still I can't find method to update combination price.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update the price of one of your combinations you'll have to call the object Combination() and use the update() function from there.